# fullcalendar resource timeline not showing all duration

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have followed the steps of the fullcalendar tutorial, and it does not show me the total duration of the event.
[This is what I get][1]

```
import {Calendar} from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interaction from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import resourceTimeline from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline';
import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/es';


let calendario = null;

function init() {
    console.info("OcupacionAulas init");
    let calendarioEl = document.getElementById('calendario-ocupacion');
    calendario = new Calendar(calendarioEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'GPL-My-Project-Is-Open-Source',
        locale: esLocale,
        timeZone: 'europe/madrid',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth,listMonth'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'hoy',
            month: 'mes',
            week: 'semana',
            day: 'día',
            list: 'lista'
        },
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
        plugins: [interaction, resourceTimeline, listPlugin],
        resources: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
        events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?single-day&for-resource-timeline'
    });

    calendario.render();
}
```

[This is how it should look][1]

Comment: Your images appear to be missing?

Comment: Without the images it's unclear what the issue is supposed to be. Please add them, then we can help you